# An irrational succession, increasing $c_i <c_{i+1}$ and that $\lim_{n\to \infty}{c_n}=1$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> I want to find an irrational succession, increasing $c_i <c_{i+1}$ and that $\lim_{m\to \infty}{c_n}=1$

my solution.

Let the sequence $$c_m=\left\{\frac{\pi+2^m-4}{2^m};m=2,3,...\right\}$$

this sequence complies that $\lim_{m\to \infty}{c_m}=1$

How prove that is increasing?

maybe prove that $c_{i+1}-c_i >0$.

then,

$$\frac{\pi+2^{n+1}-4}{2^{n+1}}-\frac{\pi+2^n-4}{2^n}>0$$

$$\frac{\pi-4}{2^{n+1}}-\frac{\pi-4}{2^n}>0$$
$$\frac{4-\pi}{2^{n+1}}>0$$
$$4>\pi$$

Does this prove that it is increasing?

Comment: When you write $\lim_{n \to \infty} c_m$ you should use the same index.  As written it makes no sense.  It should be $\lim_{n \to \infty} c_n$

Comment: yes,, im sorry :)

Comment: Well, you solved your own question. It does indeed prove that sequence is increasing

Comment: Your proof starts by assuming what you want to prove.  It should go in the reverse direction.  As each step you used is reversible, it works just fine.  You start with something clearly true, here $4 \gt \pi$ and get to the result you want.

Comment: Maybe $c_n=1-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}n$ is a simpler example.

Answer (score 0):

Take $1-\pi/n$. Clearly, it is an irrational sequence, increasing and converges to $1$.